# How to do microsoft access update query or vb function which use random unique number with in specific numbers range

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, random, insert-update

How can i write ms access update query that updates table records which uses random unique number but with in specific range.

Here what i need help with

Problem Before

id  Id1 time2   tim1
1   101 **8.12**    **9.11**
2   102 **8.20**    **9.45**
3   103 8.31    9.12
4   104 8.10    9.10
5   105 8.55    9.43

after running query

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.time2 = RanNumBtw(10,20), Table1.tim1 = RanNumBtw(10,20)
WHERE (((Table1.id1) In (101,102)));
```

Output which i don't need

id  Id1 time2   tim1
1   101 **13**      **13**
2   102 **13**      **13**
3   103 8.31    9.12
4   104 8.10    9.10
5   105 8.55    9.43

what i need as output

id  Id1 time2   tim1
1   101 **13**      **16**
2   102 **19**      **11**
3   103 8.31    9.12
4   104 8.10    9.10
5   105 8.55    9.43

Now problem what i need to do is update time2 column and tim1 column with in specific range based on id1 column.

like where id1 is 101,102 update time2 between (8.10  to 8.30) and tim1 between (9.10  to 9.30) to Random Unique number.

I have tried vb function which generate number between specified range but it update with same number again and again

```
Public Function RanNumBtw(ByVal LwLimit As Long, ByVal UpLimit As Long) As Long 
    Randomize
    RanNumBtw = Rnd * (UpLimit - LwLimit) + LwLimit
End Function
```

what this function does is it gives same number again for all cells

query or vb code will help

thanks

Comment: Function should work fine. Please share us with SQL you use for update. And please format function code as code

Comment: Thanks can you check it out now I have updated @SergeyS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as:

```
Public Function RanNumBtw(LwLimit As Long, UpLimit As Long, RandInit As Long) As Long
    Randomize RandInit + Now()
    RanNumBtw = Rnd * (UpLimit - LwLimit) + LwLimit
End Function
```

and query as:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET Table1.time2 = RanNumBtw(10,20,[id]), Table1.tim1 = RanNumBtw(10,20,[id])
WHERE (((Table1.id1) In (101,102)));
```

Access cashes function results if arguments are the same for each row.

Comment: thanks when i add (8.10,8.30) it produce 8.10235 random but i need only 2 decimal how can i do that like "8.13" @SergeyS.

Comment: Use `Round` and/or `Format` functions.

Comment: thanks for answer how can I use time between like (6:20,6:30) instead of numbers. @SergeyS.

Comment: For instance `DateAdd("n",Rnd()*10,#6:20#)`

Comment: I am using same function but it doesn't produce different random no

Comment: I am using same function but it doesn't produce different random time it produce like in column time2 : 0.2673611 same value in whole column i know its number format of time. every cell gets same its not ramdom. can you please provide vb and sql both please it will be helpful @SergeyS.

Comment: Change data type of Time columns to date/time and rewrite RanNumBtw, it should return Date data type. Use [ID] column for randomizing in each row